# Change nib programmatically when orientation changes

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, nib

I load my nibs like this in the init:

```
self = [super initWithNibName:@"PageView_iPhone" bundle:nil];
```

But how do I change this during runtime (i.e. after the init) if the orientation changes? `initWithNibName` won't work.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to load a different nib, you could use:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PageView_iPhone" owner:self options:nil];
NSArray* nibViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PageView_iPhone"
                                              owner:self
                                            options:nil];

PageView_iPhone* myView = [nibViews objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain the last line as I'm not really sure about it. Will the nib PageView_iPhone become a class and myView a subclass? Thanks a lot! ... and yes, I need to load a different nib. Autoresize won't work unfortunately.

Comment: You should use this code from outside the `PageView_iPhone` class. Typically, in the view controller that holds that view, so you can switch from the old view to the new one.

Comment: You can't load a nib once the view controller has been init'd can you?  I'm under the impression that once the nib is loaded in init, it can't load another one to replace the current one.

Comment: @frowing Thanks for the explanation. But what exactly do I do with *myView? Would I then need to assign myView to the view of the viewController? Like self.view = myView; ?

Comment: Turns out I was wrong, check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346597/iphone-orientation-and-2-nib-files

Answer (score 1):

During init, I setup my views (create them programatically) and create extra CGPoint's for center positions or CGRect's for frames for each view in the view controller.

After the views are created in init, I call method named layoutViewsForOrientation to set the initial position, passing in the current status bar orientation.  When the orientation changes, I use this code:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    BOOL result = NO;
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        result = (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
    } else {
        result = YES;
    }
    if( result == YES ) [self layoutViewsForOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
    return result;
}
```

There may be an easier way, but this works well for my needs.